# I have a custom baby gate that has two swinging doors that open either way. How do I make them swing closed when opened from either direction!

Tags: gates

I have a custom baby gate that has two swinging doors that open from either direction. How can I make them automatically swing shut when we walk through from either direction

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A diagram and/or picture would really help here.

Comment: Would a gate like this, which would pinch baby hands or heads when 'swinging' closed, be a good choice as a baby gate? If left open and a child pushes through from one side they would be trapped and pinched trying to back up.

Comment: We've got one that does this, at the bottom of the stairs. It's seriously anything when you're trying to carry stuff. It crosses the line from irritating to hazardous when you open it, pick up the baby and it shuts in front of you. We've defeated the auto close (simply by using rubber bands to pull it open)

Comment: @ChrisH  "It's seriously anything when you're trying to carry stuff"   i can not wrap my head around that sentence.

Comment: @Alaskaman swift key defeated me - it should have read "annoying"

Answer (score 1):

The design of the door would be helpful for illustrative purposes, but I think that you could probably make it work with a stiff spring.

Since this is a DIY forum, see the DIY idea below.

[image]

The idea is not to stretch the spring outward but side to side- allowing the straightening force to close the door. You may also need some medium washers to secure the spring. You can probably cover the spring with a hose or a fabric tube so that baby doesn't get pinched.

Answer (score 0):

Use double-acting spring hinges, also known as bi-swing spring hinges or double-action spring hinges.

A vendor lists some additional names:

> Saloon Door hinges, Cafe Door hinges, Swinging Door Hinges, or Double Acting Barrel Hinges.